# UIDatePIcker TouchUp Events programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift

> The following code using swift language but not worked only touchUp
>   Events to UIDatePicker.

```
  var datePickerView : UIDatePicker!
  self.datePickerView = UIDatePicker.init(frame: CGRectZero)
  self.datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NDSignUpViewController.dateAction(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
  self.dateOfBirthTextField.inputView = self.datePickerView

  func dateAction(sender: AnyObject) {
      //...
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIControlEvents.ValueChanged` instead of `UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside`. hope this will help :)

Comment: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged worked. but not work UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside

Comment: touchupinside is event for controller which don't have multiple options like button. datepicker have multiple options. if you selecting any then you are changing value. here heve to be specific because having many option. if touchup inside work then what will  be the sender ? thats why it is not working here.